# mysql server hung up because of too many connections

Tags: mysql

Our mysql server causes huge overload because of number of opened connections. In my case most connections are in opened state and I cannot even kill them. That is I cannot understand. The connections look like this:

```
    | 13927 | slimdiz1_dstream | localhost | slimdiz1_docstream         | Query      | 20   | closing tables       | SELECT autoload FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_site_transient_theme_roots'                    |
| 13934 | okanaga1_db1     | localhost | okanaga1_db1               | Query      | 5    | Opening tables       | INSERT INTO sessions VALUES('e442db394d16e7ac5d2154ae3e1ccbe4', '1306059991', 'a:5:{s:11:"LoginCooki |
| 13935 | mkca1_wrdp5      | localhost | mkca1_wrdp5                | Query      | 7    | Opening tables       | SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 1 ..
```

Connections number to the web server (max is 150):

```
    ps -e | grep httpd | wc -l
109
```

Available memory:

```
    free -mto
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7974       5565       2409          0        153       1373
Swap:         2047         31       2016
Total:       10022       5597       4425
```

MySQL server version and the configuration file:

```
    [mysqld]

safe-show-database

set-variable = max_connections=450
set-variable = interactive_timeout=150
set-variable = connect_timeout=35
set-variable = wait_timeout=70
set-variable = max_user_connections=30

set-variable = key_buffer=48M
set-variable = read_buffer=5M
set-variable = join_buffer=1M
set-variable = record_buffer=1M
set-variable = sort_buffer=2M

set-variable = table_cache=1028
set-variable = thread_cache=128

set-variable = query_cache_limit=1M
set-variable = query_cache_size=1024M
set-variable = query_cache_type=1
set-variable = thread_concurrency=4
set-variable = max_allowed_packet=5M

set-variable = delayed_insert_limit=80
set-variable = delayed_insert_timeout=200
set-variable = delayed_queue_size=700

set-variable = flush_time=300


mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.91,
Linux 2.6.38.3-grsec
```

I am killing the mysql processes when the load is too high using the following commands:

```
killall -9 httpd php
mysqladmin pr | awk {'print$2'} | xargs -i mysqladmin kill {};
```

Could you please help me understand why the processes are hung up in the opening state though there are free resources on the server?

P.S. I googled on this issue, read some articles, searched through this forum with no success.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Update. top -c output:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
    24738 mysql     20   0 1480m 310m 4612 S  70  13   7:46.33 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql
```

Comment: Whats your output of top? I had a similar problem with a cpanel server for the previous few days

Comment: Do you mean 'top' command? I updated the original post with the top output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common possible cause for SQL requests "piling up" on a server is [MySQL's/MyISAM's poor man's "locking mechanism" that even does not deserve its name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html). If you have a long-running SELECT query, any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE query writing to the tables that are used/locked by the long-running SELECT would cause a "congestion" and put a stop to any consecutive queries using any of the affected tables.

Use the `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` command in MySQL to check if you have many queries in "Locked" state when you hit this condition again.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Will do as soon as I'm on the shift and the load jumps up again.